# Javascript Functions Logic

Tags: javascript, ember.js

wanted some help with a friend's code. We're working on something together, but I'm relatively new to JavaScript. I've included the code below and would like some help understanding the logic. I've understood it for the most part, but not getting the complete picture.

```
App.SummaryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    userExpense: function() {

        var userExpenseMap = {}
        var expenses = this.get('controllers.expenses');
        expenses.forEach(function(expense){
            if(userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')]){
                userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] += expense.get('amount');
            }
            else{
                userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] = expense.get('amount');   
            }
        });
        userExpenseList = []
        for(var key in userExpenseMap){
            var obj = {};
            obj.name = key;
            obj.expense = userExpenseMap[key];
            userExpenseList.push(obj);
        }
        console.log(userExpenseList);
        return userExpenseList;
    }.property('controllers.expenses.@each.amount')  

});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part of it are you unclear about?

Comment: It is setting the value of the App.SummaryController variable to be the returned object of the Extend method (which extendeds the property `userExpense` on to the object `Ember.ObjectController`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Voting to close on principle, but good luck. can your friend not explain?

Comment: this code uses tho module pattern http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html App.SummaryController is set so that it can be used from other pages

Comment: From what I understand, the userExpenseMap takes as its input the 'obj' from the array userExpenseList. the expenses variable gives us access to the data in the expenses controller and computation is done in the forEach loop. Would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain the function, but if you are wanting the ember portion of it that opens a week long class.

```
userExpense: function() {
    // create an object (hash)
    var userExpenseMap = {}
    // in ember, grab the expenses controller, this shouldn't work, because in order to
    // access another controller he should have a needs: ['expenses'] in this controllers hash
    var expenses = this.get('controllers.expenses');
    //iterate over each expense, named expense in the iteration
    expenses.forEach(function(expense){
        // if the object hash contains the whoPaid already, increment it by this amount
        if(userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')]){
            userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] += expense.get('amount');
        }
        // otherwise create a new person who paid (as the key and set the amount)
        else{
            userExpenseMap[expense.get('whoPaid')] = expense.get('amount');   
        }
    });
    // create a global list (bad practice)
    userExpenseList = []
    // iterate through all the property names (keys) in the object hash
    for(var key in userExpenseMap){
        // set obj to a new object/hash (obj is actually hoisted out of here
        // so this isn't creating a new variable, just setting obj each time
        var obj = {};
        //set two properties on it, name and expense with the values from above
        obj.name = key;
        obj.expense = userExpenseMap[key];
        // put it into the global list
        userExpenseList.push(obj);
    }
    // print it out
    console.log(userExpenseList);
    // return it
    return userExpenseList;
}.property('controllers.expenses.@each.amount')
```

and this is a computed property in ember, that's what the `property` function at the end is, and the portion on the inside is the dependency, so any time the amount on any instance of an expense which lives on the expenses controller (which is an array) changes the property will be marked as dirty (so if someone is observing it, or depends on it, they will update.  The dependency updating etc is Ember Magic, not really Javascript related)